# Split inputTextField.text and time the display of the result

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift and I'm trying to change the [Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH22-SW1) how-to to understand it better. I created a simple single view application with this `Main.storyboard`:

[image: Screenshot]

And this `ViewController.swift`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var inputTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pauseHorizontalSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var outputLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func displaySplittedString(_ sender: UIButton) {
        outputLabel.text = inputTextField.text
    }
}
```

How can I split the string `inputTextField.text` into its characters and display each character for x milliseconds in `outputLabel.text`? `x` being the value of `pauseHorizontalSlider` which has a minimum value of 100 and a maximum value of 1000?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Look into Grand Central Dispatch, more specifically the methods to "dispatch after" which allow you to run a block of code after a delay on a thread of your choosing

Comment: There are a couple completely unrelated problems here: splitting the text into separate characters, and displaying one character at a time at intervals. I would break down the problem into parts as small as you can, research them, and ask a question here if you run into a specific issue.

Comment: For your first question, you could use inputTextField.text?.characters, then convert it to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sg. like this:

```
func show(string: String, milliseconds: Int, index: Int = 0) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(milliseconds)) {
        label.text = String(string[index])
        if index < string.characters.count - 1 {
            show(string: string, milliseconds: milliseconds, index: index + 1)
        }
    }
}

let stringArray = Array(inputTextField.text!.characters)
show(string: stringArray, milliseconds: 500)
```